# charting - multiple axes are not supported on a per series basis

Tags: dotnetcharting

I am trying to use a third party chart from [dotnetcharting](http://www.dotnetcharting.com/). It plots the chart fine however the scale does not seem to work. I have a stock chart but the chart appears like a flat line because of the scale.

```
 _ch.Type = ChartType.Financial;
 _ch.DefaultSeries.Type = SeriesTypeFinancial.Close;
 _ch.YAxis.Scale = Scale.Range;

 // populate series with price data

 _ch.SeriesCollection.Add(sc);
```

I use the debug tool and on the chart I see the message below. I can't see what I am doing wrong?

```
 multiple axes are not supported on a per series basis
```

**Update**

If I change the chart type from Financial to Combo the scale is correct. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems as a bug, I think the best you can do about it is to contact the dotnetcharting support team(support@dotnetcharting.com) and ask them. Hope you sort out your problem!

Regards,
Ramzy!